# How can I return the longest string from an array in PHP 4.0 ? I tried the max funcion but seems to throw an exception

Tags: php, html

I would like to return the longest string in an array in php 4.0 my sample code looks like this.

```
$MyArray=Array("Jane","Magdalene","Bull fighting champion","cruising","Tommy Lee Jones","View","axe");
$largest = max($MyArray); 
echo $largest.
```

Comment: Why do you have to use PHP 4.0? It is a long dead horse.

Comment: Seriously 4.0? Not at least 4.0.5 or something?

Comment: probably because he is implementing something for a huge PHP4.0 project and he just can't upgrade everything for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
$longest = $MyArray[0];
foreach( $MyArray as $str ) {
  if ( strlen( $str ) > strlen( $longest ) ) {
    $longest = $str;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`max()` is to give the maximum from a list of integers. Unfortunately, your problem is more complicated.

```
<?php
$MyArray=Array("Jane","Magdalene","Bull fighting champion","cruising","Tommy Lee Jones","View","axe");
$maxlen = 0;
$idx = -1;
for ($i=count($MyArray); $i; $i--) {
    $len = strlen($MyArray[$i-1]);
    if ($len > $maxlen) {
        $maxlen = $len;
        $idx = $i-1;
    };
}
if ($idx >0) {
    echo $MyArray[$idx];
}
```

Comment: using `for` in php for an `Iterable`. Why? for god sake why ?

Comment: Why not? Sure, there are simpler ways.

Comment: However, this runs up to 30% faster than some of the other solutions posted so far.

Comment: because there is `foreach` and its much readable and faster then `for`.

Comment: I doubt it runs faster then @William 's answer even if it does micro optimization doesn't worth to sacrifice the readability.

Comment: Actually, it does. At least in my crude benchmarks. I won't argue when it comes to readability. I shouldn't go on SO after midnight.

Comment: Hey guyz thanks for your answers. They work awesomely. However I'm not sure which is faster.

Comment: @Michael: will could be, but that is not what http://www.phpbench.com/  and some other resources suggest.

Comment: @Jack Unless you're doing this very often with large numbers of strings, it's not going to make much of a difference and I'd go with William's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$lengths = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($MyArray); $i++) {
    $lengths[$myArray[$i]] = strlen($MyArray[$i]);
}
arsort($lengths);
echo key($lengths);
```

Comment: don't use my solution... it will work but it's pretty bad... lol. I shouldn't go on stackoverflow after midnight =p

Answer (score 0):

And the compact version without manual loops:

```
$array = array_combine($array, array_map("strlen", $array));
arsort($array);
print key($array);
```

Comment: Unfortunately array_combine wasn't included until php 5.0, and the OP asked for PHP 4.0

Comment: and also `array_map` still loops through array though.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: Everyone is taking that too literally when OP probably just referred to PHP4 buzzwordwise. Should it actually be the case he could use PHP_Compat or upgradephp to get missing PHP5 features on older versions.